# Tipo (Type) en python

Tags: python, math

Desarrolle una función llamada `sum_ints` que tome como parámetro una tupla con valores de diferentes tipos y devuelva la suma de los elementos de tipo int que haya en dicha tupla.

Por ejemplo:

Entra: `(10,  "Pedro", 42, "Margarita", 18.5, 8)`

Devuelve: 10 + 42 + 8 = 60

```
MAIN.PY
import functions

t = (10,  "Pedro", 42, "Margarita", 18.5, 8)
suma = functions.sum_ints(t)
print("la suma de los elementos de tipo int de la tupla es:", suma)
```

Comment: Hola @Carl ¿tienes una duda con tu código ?

Comment: Si quieres verificar si una variable es entera es: `if isinstance(variable, int): ....`

Comment: ¿Y cuál es tu pregunta?

Comment: La duda es que no sé como continuar con el ejercicio

Comment: Tienes una lista de elementos no? recorres esta lista elemento por elemento y debes verificar si el mismo es una instancia de un objeto `int`, en los comentarios ya te han dicho como hacerlo, si es un entero lo sumas a una variable acumuladora y al final retornas la misma.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Lee todos los enlaces...

Answer (score 1):

Como ya se mencionó en los comentarios, el tipo de un elemento se puede determinar usando `isinstance()` o `type()`. Solo queda recorrer la tupla, verificar el tipo de cada elemento, si es un número entero, luego agregarlo a la suma total.

```
def sum_ints(t):
    s = 0
    for item in t:
        if isinstance(item, int):
             s += item
    return s
```

Opción para calcular la suma de una línea:

```
def sum_ints(t):
    return sum(item for item in t if isinstance(item, int))
```

Answer (score 0):

como dijo insolor puedes usar la función type(), que devuelve el tipo de lo que introduzcas en los parámetros. Pero para que sepas, existe una función llamada filter(función,lista), que filtra los elementos de una lista, enviandolos como parámetro, 1 por 1, a una función. Si dicha función devuelve True, el elemento es añadido a una segunda lista. Ejemplo:

```
respuesta = 0

def función(elemento):
    global respuesta # para poder acceder a y modificar la variable respuesta
    if type(elemento) == int:
        respuesta += elemento # incrementa la variable respuesta en elemento
        return True # hace que el elemento se filtre

lista = ["Marta",18.5,"Juan",15,6,9]

lista2=list(filter(función, lista)) # cada elemento de lista es enviado como parametro a funcion
                                    # si devuelve True, ese elemento se añade a lista2

print(lista2) # lista2 equivale a (15,6,9) 
print(respuesta) # respuesta equivale a 30
```

la ventaja de esto es que se traduce el bucle for de python a C, por lo que aumenta la velocidad de procesado. si la lista para filtrar tuviera una longitud de, por ejemplo, 1000, la diferencia de velocidad sería más que evidente