# PROGRAMA SUMAR ENTEROS TYPE()

Tags: python, python-3.7

Me piden desarrollar una función llamada sum que tome como parámetro una tupla y devuelva la suma de los elementos de tipo int que haya en dicha tupla USANDO LA FUNCIÓN TYPE() que devuelve el TIPO de un OBJETO y no se como se usa dicha FUNCION

Por ejemplo:

Entra: (10, "Agua", 42, "Crack", 0, 8)

Devuelve: 10 + 42 + 8 = 60

```
"""main.py"""

import functions

t = (50, "Futbol", 69, "Comida", 125.5, 82)
suma = functions.sum_ints(t)
print("la suma de los elementos de tipo int de la tupla es:", suma)
```

Comment: Esta pregunta ya ha sido formulada [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/299709/usar-funciÓn-type-en-python) y [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/299676/7123) Parece que vais todos a la misma clase...

Comment: @abulafia, ya la marqué como duplicada. Para poder hacerlo la pregunta a la que haces referencia debe tener una respuesta, bien sea aceptada o con al menos 1 voto a favor. Saludos